# Xamarin iOS UIBezierPath change direction to bottom

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, mask, layer

I want to draw a path on a image which represent a semi progress bar in Xamarin. Then It works for the top.

But now I want to draw the bottom. But I tried tried and tried again without find anything.

The image will explain you.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG7bH.png)

The code :

```
public CircleGraph(UIImageView imageView, int lineWidth, float percentComplete) : base(imageView.Frame)
{
    Initialise(imageView, lineWidth, percentComplete);
}

void Initialise(UIImageView imageView, int lineWidth, float percentComplete)
{
    _lineWidth = lineWidth;
    _percentComplete = percentComplete;
    this.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;

    this.backgroundImage = imageView;
    Add(backgroundImage);

    centerPoint = new CGPoint(Bounds.GetMidX(), Bounds.Height);
    maskLayer = new CAShapeLayer();
    maskLayer.FillColor = UIColor.Blue.CGColor;
    maskLayer.StrokeColor = UIColor.Black.ColorWithAlpha(.5f).CGColor;
    maskLayer.LineWidth = _lineWidth;
    maskLayer.LineCap = CAShapeLayer.CapButt;

    this.Layer.Mask = maskLayer;
}

public void SetClipping(float percentComplete) {
    _percentComplete = percentComplete;
    SetNeedsDisplay();
}

public override void Draw(CoreGraphics.CGRect rect)
{
    base.Draw(rect);

    using (CGContext g = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext())
    {
        _radius = (int)(this.Bounds.Width / 2) - _lineWidth / 2;

        // Top
        var startAngle = -(float)Math.PI;
        var endAngle = startAngle + HALF_CIRCLE * _percentComplete;

        maskPath = new UIBezierPath();
        maskPath.AddArc(centerPoint, _radius, startAngle, endAngle, false);
        maskLayer.Path = maskPath.CGPath;
    };
}
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I Found it !

Just put your height's centerPoint to 0 and then play with startAngle, endAngle and clockwise and it works !